# miDebuggerPath is invalid

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to configure vscode to debug. I keep getting the error message saying my miDebuggerPath is invalid. this is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Matrix_public_test.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            //"miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "usr/bin/gdbus",
            //"miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, What environment are you trying to debug, which IDE. Please add those details. Do you get an error message. When do you get it, during launch of application ? What does it say. You need to have specific details to help the reader understand it easily and answer. Welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score -1):

### Related to JSON

Comments are not allowed in JSON.

Although very similar, just remember JSON **is not** Javascript. After removing comments your Json validates cleanly at: https://jsonlint.com/ try it.

Douglas Crockford, who popularized the JSON data format, deliberately removed comments from JSON to prevent misuse of the JSON format and keep it as a data-only format.

If you really want to have valid JSON you need to remove the comments.

### Related to the path

Your path is relative (and your platform is unclear) and you seem to need an absolute path. If your platform is UNIX-like add a slash at the beginning. If your platform is Windows then add the correct path on the correct drive.

In any case the error is because you are using a relative path. Use the absolute path, and do not mix unix-windows paths.

Comment: The first comment in `launch.json` is generated by VSCode itself, which obviously wouldn't happen if it didn't support comments in the first place.

Comment: Well vscode generates JSONC files, not JSON files. Please do not be rude, we are here to help.

Comment: Also, your platform is unclear. If you clarify that I'll update my answer.

Comment: I don't consider pointing out mistakes as being rude. Removing comments doesn't fix the problem described in the question.

Comment: Please fix your question an tag vscode and jsonc. JSON does NOT support comments. JSONC does. As per your error, I've already updated my question with the fix. I still would argue about being polite in your requests. Kindness gets you better results than being rude and not accepting self mistakes.